# Is there any way to plot lines of different lengths with bokeh?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

Both down sampling and resizing are not feasible options for me, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42333533/5699807).
I tried to pad the shorter lists with NaNs, but that threw up an error as well.

Is there any work around?
My code looks something like this:

```
from bokeh.charts import output_file, Line, save
lines=[[1,2,3],[1,2]]
output_file("example.html",title="toy code")
p = Line(lines,plot_width=600,plot_height=600, legend=False)
save(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However, as you see below you can plot two different lines with different lengths.

From Bokeh user guide on [`multiple lines:`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#multiple-lines)

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("patch.html")

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

p.multi_line([[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]], [[2, 1, 4], [4, 7, 8, 5]],
             color=["firebrick", "navy"], alpha=[0.8, 0.3], line_width=4)

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am using the [bokeh.chart Line](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/charts.html#line) and not multi_line, as you have, and that does not require me to specify X and Y values. However, this approach seems to be a good way forward, if i manage the memory overhead correctly!